# Wait for process to start on linux/(net)bsd

Tags: linux, shell, process, c, netbsd

I'm attempting to make a script which tracks how many times you execute a specific process. I want to detect when the process starts and then log it.

The psuedo-code would be something like this:

```
while (true) if (process started) then log(process)
```

Is there an easy way to do this (preferably in shell but C is also fine) on either Linux or NetBSD?

Comment: At least for Linux, have you looked at your system logs?  The system (journald) is probably already tracking this information for you.  Also, if you are determined to reinvent the wheel, you could put a script with the same name before the command you want to execute in the path.  Then have that script launch and log.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas this may work, but I'm not using systemd (void linux). is there something similar that's more portable?

Comment: Maybe you mean "I want to run binary file from a shell and wait until it returns a control to me"? In this case please read `man time`. Just don't call this thing a "process starts", that's really an "application start, some initialization and backgrounding / exit", a much more complex thing.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov No, that is not what I mean. I want to track every time an application is run. I do not care about what happens after it starts, only that I know how many times it runs

Comment: Use `auditd`. See here: https://serverfault.com/questions/736753/how-to-log-execution-of-a-specific-binary-script-using-auditd-or-other

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, if you know the name of the process (the executable path), then you can loop through `/proc/` dir for each PID and check the `exe` file in each of those PID directories. This file will be the same as the executable path of the process you're looking for.

See pseudo code:

```
proc_exe="" # The full path of the executable you're interested in checking.

for d in /proc/<pid> do;
    if [ ${d}/exe -eq ${proc_exe} ]; then
        # Found the PID of the process you're interested in.
    fi
done
```

This technique is better than systemd and friends and works on other Linux distros too.

On NetBSD, there's a file `cmdline` which gives you the whole `argv` as it went to the process. Slightly different semantics but almost same outcome.

For Linux, see [proc](https://www.mankier.com/5/proc) and for NetBSD, see [mount_procfs](https://man.netbsd.org/NetBSD-6.0/mount_procfs.8).

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally in Unix and its derivatives (including NetBSD) one way to do this is to enable process accounting.

On NetBSD process accounting can be enabled and started as follows:

```
echo accounting=YES >> /etc/rc.conf
/etc/rc.d/accounting start
```

Something similar should be possible on other BSDs and Unix derivatives.

The **sa(8)** command can be used to analyze and summarize the accounting data generated by the kernel, and by default it will print of information about each command that has been run since the current accounting file was first started, including how often each command has been run.